# Propper paginate a mongoose aggregate containing multible facets

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, fetch, aggregate

I have a nice mongoose aggregate-function with pagination (mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2) running with the folloging structure:

```
export const export = (req, res) => {
  
  const optionsPaginate = {
    offset: parseInt(req.query.skip),
    limit: parseInt(req.query.top),
  };

  const aggregate = model.aggregate([
    {$match: {some arguments in here}},
    {$fetch:{
      item1: {some stuff},
      item2: {some stuff},
      item3: {some stuff}
  ]);

  model.aggregatePaginate(aggregate, optionsPaginate, (err, results) => {
   res.json(results);
  })
};
```

As a return I get a list of items:

```
{
items: [
   {
   item1: [...],
   item2: [...],
   item3: [...],
   }
   ]
}
```

As this is an array with just one element (containing a bunch of arrays), there is no option to skip: I just can take the only/first element or nothing. How can I change the output of the aggregate from an arry to an object, so that the pagination-function can iterate over the bunch of fetch-objects? This change need to happen before the pagination is applied, otherwise mongoose-aggregate-paginate does not work.
So pagination will work, if there will be an output like

```
{
  items: [
     {
       item1: [...]
     },
     {
       item2: [...]
     },
     {
       item3: [...]
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

I tried to apply some `$replaceRoot` togther with `$arrayToObject` at the end of the pipeline but got mongoDB-errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `$arrayElemAt` to get the `n`th no of items.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      items: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$items",
              0
            ]
          },
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TOBuTTqhdJT)

If you need to remove the wrapper, you can use `$replaceRoot`

Comment: But I do not want to access these arrays, I want to transform them into propper objects so that pagination can work. I am not interestet in a singl Element. I want to transform
```
{
  item: [
        {
          'item1': [...],
          'item2': [...],
          'item3': [...]
      ]}
}
```
into 
```
{
  item: [
        {
          'item1': [...]
        },
          'item2': [...]
        },
          'item3': [...]
        }
      ]}
}
```
becaus than pagination will work.

Comment: Ok, what is your expected output

Comment: In Short: Instead of one object, a bunch of objects. Because pagination will just iterate over something, if there are more then one object.

Comment: what you have given in the example as output is same as what you gave in input.. I dont see any difference from both?

Comment: Sorry, I missed some brackets and for some reason, I can not edit any more. How ever, to make it easier to understand, I created an playground as well. As you can see, I try to change somethin with the root, but instead of on object per facets, I still get a list with only on object as output https://mongoplayground.net/p/uh5NKKBDmsh

Comment: The main point: I am happy with the output, everything is fine. But pagination is not as it will see the output as just one object. I can not skip any objects, because there is just one. I could split this one object into a bunch outside the aggregation, but that would not help for pagination as well.

Comment: I don understand the expected result, can u edit ur question and update expected result?

Comment: Thanks for your endurance! I updated the question with a more details version of the expeted output.

Comment: still your output is wrong, you miss {}, please do double check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220777/discussion-between-wien-mc-and-varman).